# Need help in mapping a radio button value to a value in json array in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to read the selected radio button and check for the match in JSON. I am using jquery ajax to get the JSON data and trying to highlight correct answer in green and wrong in red when clicking "Next Question". I am doing this check in a loop and looks like hence the conidtion is not met correctly. Can any one help in figuring out where the mistake. Here is my fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/ost2ypxj/4/

```
<body class="quiz">
        <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
        <div class="quiz-container">
          <div id="quiz"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
        <button id="next">Next Question</button>
        <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function(){

  var quizContainer = $('#quiz');
  var resultsContainer = $('#results');
  var submitButton = $('#submit');
  var output = [];
  var mq ='';
  const previousButton = $("#previous");
 // const checkAnsweButton = $("#check");
  const nextButton = $("#next");
  var total = '';
  var currentSlide = 0;


  function buildQuiz(){ 

      $.ajax({
        url: './json/qa.json',
        success: function(data){

          //console.log(data.myQuestions);
            mq = data.myQuestions;
            mq.forEach(
              (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
                const answers = [];
                for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){
                  answers.push(
                    `<label>
                      <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
                      ${letter} :
                      ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
                    </label>`
                  );
                }
                output.push(
                  `<div class="slide">
                    <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
                    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
                  </div>
                  `
                );
                quizContainer.html(output.join(''));
                const slides = $('#quiz').find(".slide");
                total = slides.length;
                showSlide(currentSlide);
              });
        }

    })        
  }

  buildQuiz();


  function showResults() {

    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;

    // for each question...
    mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // find selected answer
        const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
        const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
        const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();
        //console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())
        // if answer is correct
        if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) { 
            // add to the number of correct answers
            numCorrect++;
        }
    });
    $(resultsContainer).html(`${numCorrect} out of ${mq.length}`);
  }


  function showSlide(n) {
    //console.log(mq);
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n).addClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n-1).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n+1).removeClass('active-slide');
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
        previousButton.hide();
    } else {
        previousButton.show();
    }
    if (currentSlide === total - 1) {
        nextButton.hide();
        submitButton.show();
    } else {
        nextButton.show();
        submitButton.hide();
  }
}
var clickcount = 0;

function showNextSlide() {
const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');
  if(clickcount == 2){
    clickcount = 0;
  }

  if(clickcount == 0) {
    console.log("next clicked once");

    mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

          // find selected answer
          const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
          const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
          const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();

          //console.log(currentQuestion)

          // if answer is correct
          if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
            console.log("right answer") 
            console.log("correctAnswer - "+currentQuestion.correctAnswer)
            console.log("userAnswer - "+$('input[type=radio]:checked').val())

             // color the answers green
              answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","lightgreen");
        }
        // if answer is wrong or blank
       else {
          console.log("wrong answer")
          console.log("correctAnswer - "+currentQuestion.correctAnswer)
          console.log("userAnswer - "+$('input[type=radio]:checked').val())
        //
          // color the answers red
          answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).parent().css("color","red");
        }
        //answerContainers.find('input').eq(questionNumber).prop('disabled',true)
     });

  }
  else {
    console.log("next clicked second time");
     showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
   }


    clickcount += 1;
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  submitButton.on('click', showResults);
  previousButton.on("click", showPreviousSlide);
  //checkAnsweButton.on('click', showResults);
  nextButton.bind("click", showNextSlide);
})


{
  "myQuestions" : [
    {
      "question": "Who invented JavaScript?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Douglas Crockford",
        "b": "Sheryl Sandberg",
        "c": "Brendan Eich"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Node.js",
        "b": "TypeScript",
        "c": "npm"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which tool can you use to ensure code quality?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Angular",
        "b": "jQuery",
        "c": "RequireJS",
        "d": "ESLint"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

showNextSlide() function is where I am trying to highlight correct/wrong answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code was not able to find where to apply `css` because you where using for `loop` and it was checking for all slide instead of active slide. Now , to overcome this in below code i have added `attr` to the question div so that we can use this attr to get current question which is currently active and same we will be using to get `correctAnswer` from json data.Also, i have added `input[type=radio]:checked` so that the radio button which selected by user will get changed only with required color either `green` or `red`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var data = {
  "myQuestions": [{
      "question": "Who invented JavaScript?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Douglas Crockford",
        "b": "Sheryl Sandberg",
        "c": "Brendan Eich"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Node.js",
        "b": "TypeScript",
        "c": "npm"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which tool can you use to ensure code quality?",
      "answers": {
        "a": "Angular",
        "b": "jQuery",
        "c": "RequireJS",
        "d": "ESLint"
      },
      "correctAnswer": "d"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

  var quizContainer = $('#quiz');
  var resultsContainer = $('#results');
  var submitButton = $('#submit');
  var statusContainer = $('#status');
  var output = [];
  var mq = '';
  const previousButton = $("#previous");
  // const checkAnsweButton = $("#check");
  const nextButton = $("#next");
  var total = '';
  var currentSlide = 0;


  function buildQuiz() {
    mq = data.myQuestions;
    mq.forEach(
      (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
        const answers = [];
        for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {

          answers.push(
            `<label> <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">  ${letter} :
${currentQuestion.answers[letter]} </label>`);
        }
        output.push(`<div class="slide">
                    <div class="question" data-ques="${questionNumber}"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
                    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>  </div>  `); //^^ added data-ques attr to get curent question no
        quizContainer.html(output.join(''));
        const slides = $('#quiz').find(".slide");
        total = slides.length;
        showSlide(currentSlide);
      });
  }

  buildQuiz();


  function showResults() {

    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;


    // for each question...
    mq.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(questionNumber);
      const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();
      //console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())
      // if answer is correct
      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        numCorrect++;

      }
    });

    $(resultsContainer).html(`${numCorrect} out of ${mq.length}`);

  }


  function showSlide(n) {


    //console.log(mq);
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(0).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n).addClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n - 1).removeClass('active-slide');
    $('#quiz').find('.slide').eq(n + 1).removeClass('active-slide');
    currentSlide = n;


    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      previousButton.hide();
    } else {
      previousButton.show();
    }
    if (currentSlide === total - 1) {
      nextButton.hide();
      submitButton.show();
    } else {
      nextButton.show();
      submitButton.hide();
    }
  }
  var clickcount = 0;

  function showNextSlide() {
    let percentage = 0;
    let numCorrect = 0;
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.find('.answers');
    let currentques = $('#quiz').find('.active-slide');
    if (clickcount == 2) {
      clickcount = 0;
    }
    //to find which question is user on
    var ques_no = currentques.find(".question").attr("data-ques");
    if (clickcount == 0) {
      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers.eq(ques_no);
      const selector = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.find(selector) || {}).val();

      // if answer is correct
      if (userAnswer === mq[ques_no].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
        // color the answers green and added green to checked radio button
        answerContainers.find('input[type=radio]:checked').eq(ques_no).parent().css("color", "lightgreen");
        percentage = Math.round(((numCorrect / mq.length) * 100))


      }
      // if answer is wrong or blank
      else {
        // color the answers red and added checked radio button to color red
        answerContainers.find('input[type=radio]:checked').eq(ques_no).parent().css("color", "red");
      }

    } else {
      showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
      $(statusContainer).html(`Your test is ${percentage} % compelete`);
    }


    clickcount += 1;

  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }
  //added clicked event to call function on last question as well
  submitButton.on('click', showNextSlide);
  submitButton.on('click', showResults);
  previousButton.on("click", showPreviousSlide)
  nextButton.bind("click", showNextSlide);
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,600);
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f8f6f0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}

.question {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.answers {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.answers label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #279;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #38a;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.active-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.quiz-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#result {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.js"></script>

<body class="quiz">
  <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <div id="quiz"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
  <button id="next">Next Question</button>
  <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

Also ,above code has one flaw that when it reached last question and clicked on submit button the question will start from begining to stop this you add a counter which will check when last question reach.